# Gradle equivalent to IntelliJ's Run Options Fork Mode: Method

Tags: java, gradle, testing, intellij-idea

The tests in my java gradle-project require execution via IntelliJ and `Fork Mode` set to `Method` to work. I would like to be able to just run the tests via the default gradle-task, however i cannot find an equivalent forking option. I have tried adding to my `build.gradle`:

```
test{
   forkEvery = 1
   maxParallelForks = 1
}
```

which, unfortunately, does not produce the desired results. I also tried adding `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_METHOD)` which did not work as well. Is there a way to reproduce IntelliJ's `Fork Mode: Method` in gradle?

Comment: What do you mean method fork option? Is there one exists for Gradle? What exactly does not work - why do you need it?

Comment: I'm referring to the Run Configurations -> Modify Options -> Fork Mode -> Method in IntelliJ. You can access these settings when right-clicking on the tests-folder and choosing more Run/Debug. By not working I mean failing. Describing why the tests only work this way would exceed the scope of the question

Answer (score 2):

No, it's impossible to achieve IDEA's "fork mode: method" with Gradle. [forkEvery](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:forkEvery) works on the test class level (`forkEvery` set to 1 tells Gradle to spawn a new JVM for every test class).

I suggest you fix your tests instead. Having to run every test method in a separate JVM means that the tests are not independent and share state. That's a no no when it comes to testing.

As a (poor) workaround you could split your current class to N classes (where N is the number of test methods), every one containing a single test method and then use `forkEvery`.